# Handle custom Edit react node values on change event

Tags: reactjs, mantine

I have a table built using react mantine table, and have the following custom column on the table:

I created a key value editor for editing JSON, which works fine, but when I emit the onValuesChange event from the child component to the parent (in this case the Edit callback, I have no idea how to update the values of the row that's being edited

```
  {
      accessorKey: 'translations',
      Cell: ({ cell }) => (
        <TranslationsList
          translations={cell.getValue() as IHobby['translations']}
        />
      ),
      header: 'Translations',
      enableEditing: true,
      enableSorting: false,
      Edit: ({ cell, row, column, table }) => {
        return (
          <KeyValueEditor
            label={t('translations')}
            values={cell.getValue() as IHobby['translations']}
            onValuesChange={(values) => {
              console.log(values);
            }}
          />
        );
      },
    },
```

When I trigger the onEditingRowSaved callback I have the new values under props.values:
But it still prints the old ones.

```
    onEditingRowSave(props) {
      console.log(props);
    },
```

Expecting to be able to edit the current row's value with a custom component

Comment: Your question is slightly unclear, but are you just asking how to update a state object key in react? Generally you could do something like: `setMyState({ ...Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(myState).filter(([k]) => k !== newKey)), [newKey]: newValue})` I can post this as an answer if you want, or if you have a different question please explain